# Spring Boot + Google Vision AI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, vaadin

Good night! Guys, I need some advice from Java developers about my monkey code. I'm learning Spring Boot, and I need to make an application that can take images medium REST API or UI on Vaadin after you recognize objects on it with Google AI, the result must be saved in PgSQL + some more requirements described in README.md.

In general, I've made an outline of REST and can get ready-made recognition. But I have many questions:

1. I have to cover the code with integration + unit tests. I don't have integration questions but how to write units for SpringBoot applications, did each method need to be covered?
2. How do I automatically generate Sql INSERT for oid PgSQL tables (DataGrip, DBeaver can't do that)? I want to add this to the Flyway migration.
3. I use many to many links, how do I implement Hibernate deletion from three tables (all I know so far is how to do it in pure SQL)?
4. In handlePicrureUpload() I not only upload the image but also write the image into PgSQL tags. It's a very serious error how to run these actions only when the handlePicrureUpload() method is finished.
5. How to make multithreaded uploading and processing of images? How to track the status of each recognition, a separate controller that takes the statuses from Google Cloud?
6. How to output c /api/ai/ getAiResults() table in Vaadin. How to display the picture in the Vaadin table and how to schedule the tag list in the field (it was highly desirable to edit them).

I know that Google has all these answers, but I'm a little time constrained right now. You can hit me with a stick.

```
Cloud Vision documentation - https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs
```

Thank you to everyone who will respond!

Comment: You asked a lot of questions in a single post. :) Maybe try googling them first and ask separate questions if sth didn't worked or if you need some clarification?

Answer (score 1):

> I have to cover the code with integration + unit tests. I don't have
> integration questions but how to write units for SpringBoot
> applications, did each method need to be covered?

- unit tests are generally for each method.

> I use many to many links, how do I implement Hibernate deletion from
> three tables (all I know so far is how to do it in pure SQL)?

- JPA supports deleting records. If you have cascade delete setup between the tables you don't need to delete them one by one.

> In handlePicrureUpload() I not only upload the image but also write
> the image into PgSQL tags. It's a very serious error how to run these
> actions only when the handlePicrureUpload() method is finished.

- You are using the wrong OR operator in your `handlePicrureUpload`. It should be `||`

> -How to make multithreaded uploading and processing of images? How to track the status of each recognition, a separate controller that takes
> the statuses from Google Cloud?

- Spring provides `@Async` to execute methods asynchronously in separate thred. It sounds like you want to do some sort of queueing of requests. To start simple, you can save the request in a table 'request' and return a request id to track it. You can setup a `@Scheduled` job that reads new operations every X interval and process. You can setup a REST endpoint to return the status of request.